# How do multiple servers synchronise a database

Tags: database, synchronization, database-connection

Let's say there is a database in existence.

There are multiple servers to handle requests from clients. Every request from a client results in an update or insert command to the database.

There are multiple servers as there are lots (lets define that as 1,000,000**) of client requests per second. Another reason for having multiple servers is that if one server fails, the client can simply connect to another to continue.

But what if the server with the database on it fails? Then everything fails. So the only way around this would be to have the database locally on each server, or have several database servers.

But considering the data needs to be current on every sever. How would this be handled? When an insert or update is called, would you have to send the call the every server? Would it still be possible to have a real time application or are we talking seconds or even minutes delay for each database insert/update to complete. Also - how would locking even occur?!

How is this done in a real life situation - if at all?

** I have never managed or created a database that would handle a large amount of requests, so I don't know if this is ridiculous.

Comment: This belongs on serverfault.se

Comment: Really, I am asking about how to design and database/server...surely that is here?

Comment: You want to look at [CAP Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) because you only get to have 2/3.

Answer (score 0):

When maintaining multiple databases and wanting them to keep synchronized try using some form of *clustering* or *replication*. The best solution will be determined by a number of factors starting with the RDBMS you are using.

Comment: Given that I haven't started the project that would use this sort of thing, I could use any DBMS.